# Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true warnings

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, word-cloud

I am using the `react-wordcloud` package and whenever the size of the container changes it sorts the word cloud to fit the current (70%) screen size.

My console gets spammed by the warning:
[image]

I tried to use the package's default settings and I still got this warning.

```
import ReactWordcloud from "react-wordcloud";
const options = {
    colors: ["#FFF7E5", "#F9D3AB", "#f4cc72", "#ffbe2d", "#ffb100"],
    enableTooltip: false,
    deterministic: true,
    fontFamily: "impact",
    fontSizes: [40, 80],
    fontStyle: "normal",
    fontWeight: "normal",
    padding: 2,
    rotations: 1,
    rotationAngles: [0],
    scale: "sqrt",
    spiral: "archimedean",
    transitionDuration: 1000,
  };
return(<div
   style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
   >
   <ReactWordcloud options={options} words={props.wordCloud} />
</div>)
```

Comment: What's wrong with that warning?

Comment: It spams my console and makes it difficult to debug other things in the project.

Comment: Create an issue here https://github.com/chrisrzhou/react-wordcloud/issues probably nothing you can do

Comment: "My console gets spammed" really? Like how many messages do you get? That should be one per session, no more. If you've got more than that feel free to open an issue: https://crbug.com (And as said before it's a good idea to give a heads up at the author of your lib so that they use the best option).

Comment: Kaido, popular html5 game engines use a lot of getImageData, аnd console really gets spammed in html5 games on Phaser 2, Phaser 3

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can try this:

```
getContext('2d', { willReadFrequently: true });
```

For more information see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext

Comment: I just tried this, but the warning persist.

Comment: Same here. No effect on the warning at all...

Comment: Encountering the same issue... how would I set it to true in a p5.js sketch with multiple buffers?

Comment: Same issue. Any update as to why this setting does not get picked up?

Comment: The reason the warning will persist is that the very first call to getContext should set willReadFrequently, all subsequent seem to be ignored in chromium.

Comment: @JoelTeply +1, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74136040/21129054) explains a bit better why the first instance needs to have that property set. tldr; the buffer gets set in the gpu initially, so any following attempts to set the buffer in the cpu (for quicker read access) would be inconsequential.

Answer (score 3):

It happens to me also. I think it has to do with `Dark Reader` chrome extension.

The url referenced for the warning: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-will-read-frequently

Comment: How do you figure it is related to the DarkReader extension? (I'm using that extension as well)

Comment: by using an incognito window without the extension enabled. however it's possible other extensions that handle canvas do that. also it's possible they fixed it by now, it's an easy fix, see other answers.

Comment: Turning off this extension for the website fixed it for me. It was indeed Dark Reader in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue in phaser.js v3.55.2 by adding , {willReadFrequently: true}
to every instance of getContext("whatever") in the phaser.js file. No more warnings.